# react-leaflet Popup not showing when clicking marker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, popup, react-leaflet

I'm using react-leaflet in my ReactJS application and I tried to create markers dynamically and added popup as below code. But popup box is not showing and there is an error appear in web developer console

> TypeError: point is null

I am using react-leaflet version 2.5.0. Please kindly advise!

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { Map as Mapview, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, GeoJSON  } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import {API_URL} from "../../config/config";
import axios from "axios";
import { iconBlue, iconWell } from './icons';

//import { Popover, PopoverBody, PopoverHeader } from 'reactstrap';

class Map extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data : [],
            zoom: 2,
            //modal: false,
        };

        this.getLocationList = this.getLocationList.bind(this);
        //this.setModal = this.setModal.bind(this);
    }

    // setModal(val){
    //     this.setState({modal: val});
    // }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getLocationList();
    }

    getLocationList(){
        axios.get(API_URL + "location")
            .then((response) => {
            if(response.data.status === "success")
            {
                this.setState({data: response.data.location});
                console.log(this.state.data);
            }
        })
    }

    render() {


        return (
        <div>
            <Mapview 
            style={{ height: "480px", width: "100%" }}
            zoom={6}
            center={[19.745589, 96.15972]}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                {
                    this.state.data.map((location) => 
                    <Marker position={[location.location_lat, location.location_long]} icon={iconWell}>
                        <Popup>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br />Easily customizable.</Popup>
                    </Marker>
                    )
                }
            </Mapview>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: How does your `state` and `icon` look like?

Comment: Please see 
state:  http://prntscr.com/plwcjq
icon: http://prntscr.com/plwd0n

Comment: Both seem ok, there must be something wrong with the response then from the API call and the data you get. Could you include a small sample of the data you are fetching?

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, Please see the response payload here: http://prntscr.com/pm2jly

Comment: Here is the console log in web-developer tool when I click on marker: http://prntscr.com/pm2kcv

Comment: I just find out that popup not work if we assign custom icon for the marker. Popup works well with default marker. Strange! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no `point` variable or property in your code, therefore I am not really sure why you get this error.

So I do not see the error's possible cause if we take into account the code you have posted.

Let's assume you fetch successfully the data and you set the state variable data an array of objects. Then your code should look like this [in the demo page](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-popup-not-showing-when-clicking-marker-2yqe9), of course by including the fetching code using componentDidMount as in your example (here using static data just to illustrate an example)

If the data you are fetching is an object and not an array then your iteration here `this.state.data.map` is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I found what my code is required after I visit to your sample code at codesandbox.io. Popup is not showing up because I set: iconAnchor: null  and  popupAnchor: null. And didn't set value in those properties of icon. And now it works. Thanks a lot your kind help.